# get_posts function not returning any results

Tags: wp-query, plugin-wpml

I'm currently working with WP and also using WPML. I'm trying to retrieve posts using the function `get_posts` but the function is not working. This is what I'm trying so far.

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
 'post_type' => 'location',
 'numberposts' => -1,
 'suppress_filters' => 0
));
```

As shown in the picture below I have many posts with the type of location. [image]

I'm setting `numberposts` to `-1` to get all the posts and also settings and also setting `suppress_filters` to `0` and also tried `false`. What should I try If I were to get all the posts for example `es` in spanish?

Even if I remove `'suppress_filters' => false,` I still dont get any results back, althought there are many `location` posts.

Comment: The get_posts args seem ok, so where are you calling this from inside your WP site?

Comment: I'm calling it within a `register_rest_route` function

Comment: Perhaps you need to give more code context, to help others provide a good answer.

Comment: The `suppress_filters` param is boolean so true or false are acceptable values.  The default is false so if that is your wish, no need to include it.  I believe Q is on the right track with the above comment.  The placement of your code matters.  Is this query within the callback you pass in the arguments?